# How to extract values of the Keys from an array of collections in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to get the values of the keys in an array from a series of collection. Please find the snippet of code and expected output. I would
be grateful if you can help me with what should go into the aggregate phase to get the desired output. Please note there will be more than 5000 collections

```
db.collection1.insertMany([{
    item: "journal",
    qty: 25,
    tags: blank
  },
  {
    item: "mat",
    qty: 85,
    tags: gray
  },
  {
    item: "mousepad",
    qty: 25,
    tags: gel
  }
])

db.collection2.insertMany([{
    abc: "paplu",
    qiity: 01,
    thugs: red
  },
  {
    abc: "mat",
    qiity: 85,
    thugs: gray
  },
  {
    abc: "mousepad",
    qiity: 25,
    thugs: gel
  }
])

var a = ["collection1", "collection2"];


for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
db[a[i]].aggregate([])};



Expected Output:
collection1
{
item : ["journal","mat","mousepad"],
qty : [25,85,25],
tags : [blank,gray,gel]
}
collection2
{
abc : ["paplu","mat","mousepad"],
qiity : [01,85,25],
thugs : [red,gray, gel]
}





Please note, I'm trying to achieve this using MongoDB/JavaScript

It would be great if someone can help me with this!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to get keys from `ROOT` object into an array. Then you can run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `null` with [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) to get single document which contains unique key names from entire collection. In the last step you need to convert an array back to single document using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html), [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: { kv: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } }
    },
    {   $unwind: "$kv" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            keys: { $addToSet: "$kv.k" }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: { input: "$keys", in: [ "$$this", 1 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iS4TmxRtwr4)